Use service account from google to send emails through smtp.gmail.com
I'm trying to use a gmail account that I've using so far to relay emails automatically with a web app. Using the email and password, being insecure and therefore not allowed from the 30th September. I want to use the service account provided, as the 2-step confirmation method doesn't suit. So I'd like to use the service account with access token.
The token is generated in the credential with this statement.
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(fileStream)
                   .createScoped(ImmutableSet.of("https://mail.google.com/",
                               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"))
               .setExpirationTimeMilliseconds(1200000L);

I got the access token, then trying to send the emails with java mail and the following properties:
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth.login.disable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth.plain.disable", "true");
        
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "service_account_email");

And using the java Authenticator to set the email (service account email) and password (access token). I've tried using the service account email and the main account, but when trying to authenticate with Sasl XOAUTH2 method, it fails.
I'd like to use the G api for sending emails, but the system as it is currently configured, needs to relay the emails through java mail library and not the google api.
The SMTP trace:
EHLO ----
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO ----
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Authenticate with SASL
DEBUG SMTP: SASL mechanisms allowed: XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: SASL Mechanisms:
DEBUG SMTP:  XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: 
DEBUG SMTP: SASL client XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: SASL callback length: 2
DEBUG SMTP: SASL callback 0: javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback@2e539008
DEBUG SMTP: SASL callback 1: javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback@763557bd
DEBUG SMTP: SASL authentication failed

The SMTP code received when the authentication failed was 555.

Already solved. The service account needed the set up of domain-wide delegation, with the scopes https://mail.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send and the email sender had to be the same set as Delegate when creating the credential

is the email address you are sending from a google workspace domain account?

Yes, it is from the domain account and the one stated as delegated when getting the GoogleCredential. So, it already works, now it's sending the emails correctly.
